# In sftp://user:pass@something@ipaddress:port what is something?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, automation, sftp, winscp

I am reading some batch script files trying to work out where a certain file is being uploaded to (and from) and the initial open command looks like (changed of course):

```
open sftp://user:pass@something@99.999.999.999:22
```

but I cannot workout what the `something` is between password and IP address.

I looked through the documentation at WinSCP but I couldn't find anything that pointed to the answer.

Comment: Nevermind I missed the obvious, the @ symbol was part of the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open sftp://user:pass@something@99.999.999.999:22
```

username: `user`
Password: `pass@something`
sftp address: `99.999.999.999:22`

Comment: Note that while the URL works in WinSCP, it's not a good idea to write URL like this. It's ambiguous and confusing. Better is to URL-encode the `@` to `%40`. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url